# Counting exceptions via PerformanceCounter

Tags: c#, exception, performancecounter

I'm trying to count the total amount of Exceptions thrown within a Program. My setup with the `PerformanceCounter` looks right, however the output it gives doesn't make any sense.

Here's what I've written:

```
PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter();
pc.CategoryName = ".NET CLR Exceptions";
pc.CounterName = "# of Exceps Thrown";
pc.InstanceName = "_Global_";
pc.BeginInit();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception!");
    }
}
pc.EndInit();
Console.WriteLine("CounterName: " + pc.CounterName);
Console.WriteLine("CounterHelp: " + pc.CounterHelp);
Console.WriteLine("CounterType: " + pc.CounterType);
Console.WriteLine("RawValue: " + pc.RawValue);
```

And here's the console output:

```
Exception!
Exception!
Exception!
Exception!
Exception!
CounterName: # of Exceps Thrown
CounterHelp: This counter displays the total number of exceptions thrown since t
he start of the application. These include both .NET exceptions and unmanaged ex
ceptions that get converted into .NET exceptions e.g. null pointer reference exc
eption in unmanaged code would get re-thrown in managed code as a .NET System.Nu
llReferenceException; this counter includes both handled and unhandled exception
s. Exceptions that are re-thrown would get counted again. Exceptions should only
 occur in rare situations and not in the normal control flow of the program.
CounterType: NumberOfItems32
RawValue: 38790
```

I've made it so that a total of five exceptions are thrown, which, judging by the console output, works fine. Also, `CounterHelp` suggests that this counter should, in theory, produce the result I am looking for.

However, I can't seem to retrieve the acutal number of exceptions as counted by the `PerformanceCounter`. 38790 seems a little high. (This number changes when the code is run multiple times.)

What am I doing wrong? Is my approach right, or am I completely barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you're using the wrong perf counter. The one you're using is a read-only global instance; what I think you need is a writable instance local to your application. (I don't have a lot of perf counter experience, so I could be wrong.)